# What's a model controller used for?

Tags: php, laravel

I just scaffolded a model with a controller the controller had a bunch of empty methods (`create`, `edit`, etc..) I am wondering what this for,  because I can already `create` and `edit` model instances so those functions are seemingly useless.

I couldn't find anything on it in the model page in the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create, Update, Read, Delete we call CRUD. In the controller, it's helpful when you use the [`resource` route/controller](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Because the first request comes to the controller, then you can define your way around.

1. Create: The create method is for creating a new instance. It handles the HTTP `GET` request. (create form)
2. Store: The store method is for processing the form submission from the create method. It handles the HTTP `POST` request.
3. Edit: The edit method is for displaying a form to edit an existing one. It handles the HTTP `GET`. (edit form)
4. Update: The update method is for processing the form submission from the edit method. It handles the HTTP `PUT` or `PATCH` request. (edit form)
5. Delete: The destroy method is for deleting an existing instance. It handles the HTTP `DELETE` request.

[image]

Comment: soo from understanding, this controller creates api routes to those functionalities so that I can access it from my app, well, why would that be any better than simply executing the create or edit eloquent command directly in my app?

Comment: @YusufBouzekri - You create a route (which is the URL) and tell the route to call a specific controller method (like your `create()` method). Your controller method essentially just handles the request, what it should do etc (you might add validation before creating it and return an error if it fails) and what it should return. The model shouldn't know or care about where the data comes from or what format it is at (HTML form/json etc), or what it should return (HTML template/json etc). That should be handled by the controller,